# how does odom to map drift affect to nav2?

Tags: ros2, nav2

I'm using [nav2 GPS WP Logger and follower](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html) on a real robot on an outdoor environment.
First I drive the robot with a joystick and log each WP. Then I run nav2 on the robot and Rviz on a laptop. Unfortunately the robot doesn't follow the exact logged WP. It's out for a few meters. I'm trying to understand why is this happening.
The first thing I've noticed is that as my robot moves the tf between map and odom drift. That is, odom frame is moving around from 0 to 2mts from map frame. I'm wondering how this affect to navigation. I saw global cost-map is in map frame, but local cost-map is in odom frame.
Does nav2 using WP goals in odom frame or in map frame?
Could it be the map-odom drift responsible for WP-goals offset?